# New IDENTITY column on existing table - what will be the order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity, clustered-index

I added an `IDENTITY` column to an existing table in SQL Server 2012. Expected the numbers to be generated in the order of clustered index (non-sequential GUID), but to my surprise they got generated in the order of one of the indexes which is not even unique, and also coincidentally exactly the order I wanted!

Can anyone explain this? Here are the details of the table:

```
   id - guid (non-sequential), clustered index, primary key
   eventdate - bigint (unix date), not null, non-unique index
   more columns, some indexed, all indexes non-unique
```

Identity values got assigned in the order of `eventdate`. I even found a few examples where several rows had the same `eventdate`, and they always had sequential identity numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742.aspx) that the order in which identity values are generated for the new column of existing table is not defined.

> `IDENTITY`
>
> Specifies that the new column is an identity column. The
>   SQL Server Database Engine provides a unique, incremental value for
>   the column. When you add identifier columns to existing tables, the
>   identity numbers are added to the existing rows of the table with the
>   seed and increment values. **The order in which the rows are updated
>   is not guaranteed.** Identity numbers are also generated for any new
>   rows that are added.

So, you'd better check thoroughly that you got new `IDENTITY` values in the order that you need. Check all rows of the table.

**Edit**

"The order is not guaranteed" doesn't mean that it is random, it just means that optimizer is free to pick any method to scan the table. In your system it apparently picked that index on `eventdate` (maybe it has the least amount of pages), but on another hardware or another version of the server the choice may change and you should not rely on it. Any change to the table structure or indexes may change the choice as well. Most likely the optimizer's decision is deterministic (i.e. not random), but it is not disclosed in the docs and may depend on many internal things and may change at any time.

Your result is not unexpected. Identity values were assigned in some unspecified order, which coincided with the order of the index.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I did know the identity order was not guaranteed - hence the surprise when I added and removed the column several times, and got the same unexpected result every time. Also I did check every row - I ran a query that for each row tries to find another row, where identity is larger but eventdate is smaller. The query returned no results.

Comment: @Andrew, "the order is not guaranteed" doesn't mean that it is random - see the edited the answer.